# (C#) Como posso substitui um caractere especifico "x" por "y" em uma String?

Tags: c#, regex

To querendo fazer uma função que consiga substituir um valor  em caractere( "@" ) por valor "A" dentro da string. Supondo que a entrada seja `"@@bbcc@@"`, então a função retorna `"AAbbccAA"`  .

Comment: Se for caracteres específicos, por exemplo, o @ para o A, utilize a função `Replace` do C#, desta forma: 
String str = "@@bbcc@@";
str = str.Replace("@", "A").Replace("Caractere", "Letra").Replace("Caractere", "...")

Answer (score 3):

Tente utilizar o código abaixo.

```cs
String s = "@@bb@@@";
    
s = s.Replace("@", "A");
```

O método Replace da classe String irá substituir todas as ocorrências de @ por A.
Recomendo que vocÊ estude a documentação abaixo também.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

Como você especificou a tag [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) na sua pergunta, para fazer a mesma coisa utilizando expressão regular seria o equivalente à:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string s = "@@bbb@";

string S = Regex.Replace(s, @"@", "b");
```

Comment: Eu utilizei a classe [RegularExpressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) tb, mas eu não consegui utiliza-lo de uma forma organizada para resolver o meu  problema ... :/

Comment: Qual foi o problema que você teve @causticroot?

Comment: Eu encontrei uma solução meio confusa, li a documentação  mas essas classes  que manipulam  String tem uns  comportamentos bem parecidos... como comecei estudar agora pouco acabei me confundindo um pouco. Compartilhei abaixo como eu resolvi utilizando o `Regex.Replace`

Comment: Se tiver dúvidas sobre o método que houve confusão, compartilhe conosco com uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O que eu estava resolvendo era isso:

> Gordon Ramsay shouts. He shouts and swears. There may be something
> wrong with him.
>
> Anyway, you will be given a string of four words. Your job is to turn
> them in to Gordon language.
>
> Rules:
>
> Obviously the words should be Caps, Every word should end with '!!!!',
> Any letter 'a' or 'A' should become '@', Any other vowel should become
> '*'.

Acabei achando um exemplo com o uso da classe [StringBuild](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder) e foi a forma mais legível de resolver, vou compartilhar aqui os caminhos que segui:

### o primeiro, meio embaraçoso e confuso:

```
public class Kata
{
  public static string Gordon(string a)
  {
    a = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(a, "[eiou]", "*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace("[aA]", "@");
    return a = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(a, "a", "@", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(" ", "!!!! ").ToUpper() + "!!!!";
  }
}
```

---

### O segundo, mais compreensível :

```
public class Kata
{
    public static string Gordon(string a)
    {
        StringBuilder frase = new StringBuilder(a);
        frase.Replace("a", "@")
            .Replace("e", "*")
            .Replace("i", "*")
            .Replace("o", "*")
            .Replace("u", "*")
            .Replace(" ", "!!!! ");
        string fraseNova = string.Format("{0}!!!!", frase).ToUpper();
        return fraseNova;
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Um lança-foguetes contra uma formiga. Toda esta lógica é necessária para um trabalho tão simples que já vem pronto no Framework?

Comment: Lembrando que a minha intenção é entender como funcionava o processo, e para isso tentei buscar um exemplo que me ajudasse a entender melhor.  Ainda estudo, o meio de solucionar foi a nível  de conhecimento mesmo, não de buscar a solução menos custosa ou a mais correta, porém compreendi o seu ponto de visto, reconheço que exista formas melhores de resolver.